# append headers using axios intceptor

Tags: vue.js, axios

My question is very specific and I have searched for it but did not find a good answer. I am not trying to simply add a header through the request interceptor, but I want to append to it. For example I have multiple services that define their own headers and pass that through configuration options object. However, I want to append an additional header to those headers, but when I tried the interceptor in the following manner, I do not seem to have access to the existing headers:

```
axiosIntance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    console.log(config); // do not have access to existing header that was added using options 
});
```

I am trying to do something that is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured a way to do it.. It may help others.. I am still open to better options..

```
axiosIntance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers = {'X-Some-Custom-Header': 'custom-header-value', ...config.headers} ;
    // basically the spread operator would preserve the original headers and add to it 
});
```